# How can I implement Facebook chat vertical scrollbar style?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollbar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook's horizontal scrollbar in ticker & chat sidebar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299426/facebooks-horizontal-scrollbar-in-ticker-chat-sidebar)

I am implementing a div with inner content as overflow-y: auto. But I need to change the style of the scrollbar and make it similar to Facebook chat scrollbar style.

Code:

```
<div style='overflow-y: auto; overflow-x:hidden;'>
<div id='divInner1'>Some Content</div>
<div id='divInner2'>Some Content</div>
<div id='divInner3'>Some Content</div>
<div id='divInner4'>Some Content</div>
<div id='divInner5'>Some Content</div>
</div>
```

How can I style scrollbar vertical for the outermost div with styling same as that of facebook?

Comment: I have tried to put some style. But i am not able to decrease the with and make it thin as Facebook chat vertical scrollbar.                     overflow: auto;  
    scrollbar-face-color: #c4c4c4;
    scrollbar-base-color: #f6f6f6;
    scrollbar-arrow-color: #c4c4c4;
    scrollbar-track-color: #f6f6f6;
    scrollbar-shadow-color: #c4c4c4;
    scrollbar-highlight-color: #c4c4c4;
    scrollbar-3dlight-color: #c4c4c4;
    scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #c4c4c4;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at: http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/demo.html

Comment: Yes i can use that but in IE i am asked always to allow blocked content popup due to third party jquery is there any way to avoid that? apart from changing IE browser settings?

Comment: Did you add the files on your own server? I don't see why IE is blocking this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this has to be styled for each browser engine seperately. For Chrome and Safari, here is a very good description about how to do so.
http://www.webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/