# How can I set a height of document

Tags: javascript, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a custom scrollbar on a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945547/how-to-create-a-custom-scrollbar-on-a-div)

I'm having the following body

```
<div id="app-container">
    <div id="canvas-container">
        <div id="canvas"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In CSS I have:

```
#canvas {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#app-container {
  height: auto !important;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#canvas-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

after that I'm adding divs (with jquery.appendTo and jquery.offset) to `<div id="canvas"></div>` with

```
display: inline-block;
position: absolute;
```

in CSS. So adding such a div cannot affect document size. If I add many divs some of them can be located below the edge of screen. How can I add a scrollbox, so that I can see all of divs?

Comment: change overflow to "scroll".

Comment: Can you share your code on "http://jsfiddle.net/"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property `overflow: auto` and `height: (required height)` inside the `#canvas` should make all the divs inside that visible.

I have used this few times in my application. Hope I didn miss anything thats very obvious.