# creating the same scroll bar style effect in all browsers css or jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

Hi i am trying to get my websites scroll bars to look the same in all browsers. i am trying to do this with jquery but not having any luck getting one to work, can i not just do this in css?

Would appreciate any tutorial links or any push in the right direction. thanks

Comment: What have you tried? Also, this might help: http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_scrollbars.cfm

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945547/how-to-create-a-custom-scrollbar-on-a-div

Comment: websites don't need to look the same in all browser (just need to look good!); styling scrollbar is highly unreliable ;then using js is adding up on code/memory usage/execution...+ it might confuse some users not so sawy that are used to their scrollbar =very bad idea !

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  [This page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) will help you improve your chances of getting good answers here.

Answer (score 0):

From a similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725652/css-scrollbar-style-cross-browser):

> Scrollbar CSS styles are an oddity invented by Microsoft developers. They are not part of the W3C standard for CSS and
>   therefore most browsers just ignore them.

Nevertheless, [jScrollPane](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html) seems to be a solution that is quite suitable for *most* browsers.