# DIV with rounded corners and internal scrollbars

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to achieve a scenario where a DIV has internal scroll bars and rounded corners.  My first attempted resulted in this:

[image]

The right hand corners become square, on account of the scroll bars.

Next, I added an internal div with some top and bottom padding, in order to push the scrollbars down and maintain the counted corders.  That came out like this:

[image]

I'd like a hybrid where the scroll bars are the full length of the div but don't make the corners square.  Is this possible?

Comment: could you share your html and css with us?

Comment: After searching around some more and seeing some other opinions out there, I think I will end up either living with the browser scroll bar or using a custom scroll bar like JScrollPane.  Thanks for the input!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try a custom scrollbar. On your screenshots you're on a OS X System, but with IE (Windows) it'll be awfull.

Take a look on [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945547/how-to-create-a-custom-scrollbar-on-a-div).

Comment: If this question is a duplicate of the one you've linked to, you should flag it as such.

Comment: It's not a duplicate but a solution

Comment: The rounded corners part is definitely the crux of this question which should never have been closed. At least in its current form it's as clear as could be.

Comment: My solution to this is to set `::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb { border-width: 5px 5px 5px 0; border-color: transparent; }` and `::-webkit-scrollbar { background: none; }` The trick here is that first part - the thumb (draggable piece) is given a border (which pushes the scrollbar away from the edges of your rounded box) but that border is invisible so it has the effect of achieving the OP question. I'd put a proper answer but this question is closed. That's not a complete working example but it's the trick to get it working.

Answer (score 16):

You can use `border-radius` the surrounding container(`scrollbar-track`) of the scrollbar (`scrollbar-thumb`).

**example:**

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
```

**jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p2bWf/**

**source: http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/**

Comment: That is a nice looking solution, however, it needs to work in more than just Chrome.  Opening this in FF shows a similar result to my first image.  I don't think I can use this.