# scrollbar customization effect not present in IE and firefox

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, webkit

My project needs this scroll bar (image given),

[image]I applied this to my css

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 8px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
} /* the new scrollbar will have a flat appearance with the set background color */

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      background-color: rgba(242,91,32,0.9); 
} /* this will style the thumb, ignoring the track */

::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

but when i checked my page only chrome is showing the effect Firefox (27.0.1) and Internet Explorer(10for) are not responding to the changes.What I must add so that it becomes uniform for all of them ?

Comment: firefox is not a webkit browser, you may want to use a jquery/JavaSceript polyfill

Comment: is "polyfill" the thing i need to use ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945547/how-to-create-a-custom-scrollbar-on-a-div

Comment: try this, nice and simple http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/basic.html

Comment: If you need fully CSS customizable scrollbar, try [jQuery Scrollbar](http://gromo.github.io/jquery.scrollbar/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by N.Nihar in a comment, Firefox and Internet Explorer in current versions don't support scrollbar customisation.

If you need to have the scrollbar styled, you may want to use a custom Javscript or perhaps even better a jQuery based scrollbar element. The first one to show up in google search is a [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945547/how-to-create-a-custom-scrollbar-on-a-div),  or you can go for the [Tiny scrollbar](http://baijs.com/tinyscrollbar/), or one from [this list](http://www.jqueryrain.com/2012/07/jquery-scrollbar-plugin-examples/). There are plenty of Javascript and jQuery based scrollbars readily available.

If you do use one of those, though, be sure to test your solution thoroughly, because the behaviour of 'native' scrollbars is not that easy to mimic.

Answer (score 0):

firefox and IE doesn't have capabilities for customizing scrollbar

Comment: what should I do to get that effect in all 3 then