# Is it possible to overlay a DIV over the browser's scrollbar?

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to overlay a DIV over the browser's scrollbar?

I realize the scrollbar can be hidden using `overflow: none`, but I'm wanting to actually put a DIV over the scrollbar instead of hiding it.

Comment: You can hide the scrollbar, and then create a scrollbar yourself with javascript, and then overlay a `div` on top of that. Please don't do this. You don't want to put anything over a scroll bar.

Comment: Yes, use chrome and hope yours bugs out like mine: https://i.imgur.com/IHEziKK.png (It's put my scrollbar into overlay mode yet if I open it in a new tab, it's the normal scrollbar. Like so: https://i.imgur.com/Jkbw7S8.png

Answer (score 7):

You can place your div over scroll bar if that scroll is not for `<html>` element. Here is code which makes overflowed div over scrollbar of another div.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69Luho03/)

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="content">
        Code goes here instead of BODY
        <div class="test"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="overflow">CONTENT FOR OVERFLOW ELEMENTS</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
}
#content {
    background: lime;
    overflow: auto;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.overflow {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 10px;
    background: blue;
}

.test {
    background: red;
    height: 1000px;
    margin: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Beat me to it! [Here's another fiddle that show this off](http://jsfiddle.net/nLvn1suv/).

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot render content outside the viewport. However, you can remove the browser's scrollbar and substitute your own, allowing much greater flexibility.

See [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945547/how-to-create-a-custom-scrollbar-on-a-div) for more information.

Comment: @manuc66, I don't see how that's in any way relevant to this topic.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at a document in google docs, this is very similar to what they do to show their own scroll bar.

If you hide the scrollbar using `overflow:hidden`, then you are free to create your own element on the right hand side of your page.  You won't be "overlaying" the browser's scroll bar.  Instead your scrollbar will simply be in the same location as the browser's was before you hid it using `overflow:hidden`.

You will plunge yourself into the fun challenge of emulating the scrollbar's behavior, with everything from dragging, clicking on the page up/down areas, etc. and moving your content in response.

Comment: `overflow: none;`?

Comment: @Brandito Jeopardy!

Comment: Much better @AaronLS

Comment: @Brandito Yeh, the original question asked about `overflow:none` and offhand I didn't notice the error.

Comment: If I was in charge of the property values I would have chosen 'none' over 'hidden'.

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot unless you write your own scrollbar implementation.

The drawbacks of writing your own scrollbar implementation include lack of testing and support for other devices.

However, [this library](https://github.com/mzubala/jquery-custom-scrollbar) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945547/how-to-create-a-custom-scrollbar-on-a-div) may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can not place a div outside the document/viewport. However you are able to hide the scrollbar and take its place in with a div or custom scrollbar.

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/5ypvbpnf/2/)

css

```
#scrollbardiv{
    height:100%;
    width:12px;
    background:red;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
}

.noscrl{
    overflow:hidden;
}
body{
    overflow:auto;
}
```

js

```
$("#toggle").on("click", function(){

  $("body").toggleClass("noscrl");

})
```