# How to convert following JS to JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm having a hard time converterting the following JS to JQuery.

My project have a `#HoverMe` div where I hover it to display the content inside `#hidden` div.

I've a well working JS script from ( [this question, by anied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39939485/js-scroll-a-hover-related-div/39939793?noredirect=1#comment67161305_39939793)). I tried to re-write `document.getElementById("HoverMe");` to `$("#HoverMe").hover(function() {` etc, but I can't go any further as  my understanding in jQuery is zero.

This is how my divs look like

```
                      ------------     --------- _
                     |  #HoverMe   |  | #hidden |S| //hover #HoverMe to display #hidden                           
                      ------------    | --------|R|
                                      | car.name|O|       
                                      |---------|L|
                                      | car.name|L|
                                       ---------|B|
                                      | car.name|A|
                                      |---------|R|
                                      | car.name| |
                                       ---------|_|
<div>
    <div id="HoverMe" style="width: 100px; background: green">
        Car
    </div>
    <div id="hidden" style="overflow:auto; height:100px; position: absolute; background-color: red; display: none">

        @foreach (var car in Model.Car) { @* Where the #hidden list get its content *@
            <div>@car.Name</div>
       }

    </div>
</div>
```

**How to convert following JS to JQuery?**

```
    var hoverEle = document.getElementById("HoverMe");
    var popupEle = document.getElementById("hidden");
    var timeoutId;

    function showPopup() {
        var hoverRect = hoverEle.getBoundingClientRect(); // get the position of the hover element
        popupEle.style.left = (hoverRect.right + 16) + "px";
        popupEle.style.top = hoverRect.top + "px";
        popupEle.style.display = "block";
    }

    function hidePopup() {
        popupEle.style.display = "none";
    }

    hoverEle.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
        showPopup();
    }, false);

    hoverEle.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
        timeoutId = window.setTimeout(function () {
            hidePopup();
        }, 1500);
    }, false);

    popupEle.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
        if (timeoutId) {
            window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        }
    }, false);

    popupEle.addEventListener('mouseout', function () {
        timeoutId = window.setTimeout(function () {
            hidePopup();
        }, 1500);
    }, false);

</script>
```

Comment: @developernator The question is not the same.

Comment: You're posting the same code asking the same thing. Take a look through your answers on the same question you asked and hour ago.  Look at djxak's answer.

Answer (score 1):

So, tips on converting JS to jQuery:

- You can select elements using simple CSS selectors.  So `var hoverEle = document.getElementById("HoverMe");` becomes `var hoverEle = $('#HoverMe');`
- Adding event listeners is done by leveraging the jquery [`.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method.  So `hoverEle.addEventListener('mouseover', function () { showPopup(); }, false);` becomes (without any delegating) `hovereEle.on('mouseenter', function () { showPopup(); });`
- CSS can be altered using the [`.css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method
- Simple hiding and showing can be toggled using [`.hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [`.show`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) methods.

Also, a great quick reference/cheatsheet for jQuery is https://oscarotero.com/jquery/

Comment: Added this for completeness's sake-- however, not sure if this is SO kosher since I answered it in the comment of another of OP's questions.  To the moderators-- if this is problematic I'll gladly remove the answer.

Answer (score 1):

to select elements using its id

this is you have done with **js**

```
var hoverEle = document.getElementById("HoverMe");
var popupEle = document.getElementById("hidden");
```

this is how you can do same thing like above using **jQuery**

```
var hoverEle = $("#HoverMe") // this select the element which its id="HoverMe"
```

like this , you can select other elements also. if it is id you should use `#` and if it is class you should use `.`.

follow is an example of using `mouseenter` an `mouseleave` using `jQuery`

```js
$("#Hoverme").mouseenter(function(){
  $(this).css({"height":"auto"},1000); 
});


$("#Hoverme").mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).css({"height":"35px"},1000); 
});
```

```css
div#Hoverme{
  width:100px;
  height:35px;
  overflow:hidden;
  }

ul li{
  list-style-type:none;
  cursor:pointer;
  background-color:orange;
  color:black;
  text-align:center;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="Hoverme">
   <ul>
     <li>one</li>
     <li>two</li>
     <li>three</li>
     <li>four</li>
     <li>five</li>
     <li>six</li>
   </ul>
<div>
```

above is a simple example of using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. this can do in various and nicely. get the idea and moderate it that fit for you.