# Can't place pointer over scroll bar

Tags: html, css

I want to place an ul li with triangular pointer over a scrollbar, like in the picture [image]

I've created the pointer but i can't get it to be over the scroll bar... I've tried z-index but it's not working.

```
ul.faq_questions li:after {

content: "";
position: absolute;
width: 10px;
height: 10px;
background:#5d3c95;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
right: -5px;
top: 40%;
z-index: 10;

}
```

Here is my [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/N3awMbbLbwadH5XSlsNS?p=preview)

Comment: I don't think you can draw anything over browser's scrollbars (or if so, it may behave differently on different browsers). So maybe create your own scroll bar instead?

Comment: No you can not do this. You can create your own scrollbar more about this look at the following topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945547/how-to-create-a-custom-scrollbar-on-a-div-facebook-style

Comment: Quinz - thanks, i did  - i got the scroll bar from here https://codepen.io/thetallweeks/pen/EaBpx

Comment: if you use position:fixed instead of absolute it would work. but you then need javascript to position it correctly

Comment: Mihai - i've tried it.. messed up the li.... thanks

Comment: how could it mess up the li ? :) using position fixed make the `:after` stay 'relative' to the entire document. so it won't stay relative to it's parent ( li ) . that's why you would need javascript to position each `:after` to it's corresponding `li`

Comment: Yeah well...it did so be cause i didn't used JS... i'm trying to work it out now....

Comment: I didn't manage to fix it with JS, can you elaborate please?