# How to make "Custom Scrollbar" in css with circle at end of scrollbar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[image: ScrollBar]

I have used **::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb** but nothing happen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a custom scrollbar on a div (Facebook style)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945547/how-to-create-a-custom-scrollbar-on-a-div-facebook-style)

Comment: What do colors mean? Red is for readed and gray is for unread? What does a red dot mean? You are here?

Comment: Yes red is for readed and grey is for unread part

Comment: Which browser are you using? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @Ouroborus I am using Google Chrome

Comment: you can use http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/complete_examples.html

Comment: I used that too @SuperUser

Comment: @AbhishekShah If you're using Manos' jQuery Custom Content Scroller, then you should be following the instructions for theming it: http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/#styling-section