# Scrollbar onMouseOver

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I saw this effect on YouTube (Home > Subscriptions Section), and I love it.
It looks like there is no scroll-bar at all, but when you hover with the mouse, it "shows up"

See picture:

[image: Left - no scroll, right - scroll]

I really like the way it looks, I would like to reproduce this somehow.

Comment: Similar Question here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125185/hide-scrollbar-and-show-on-hover-like-facebooks-new-chat-sidebar

Comment: I did try to search but couldn't find that :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is relatively simple, just have `overflow: hidden` then on `:hover` make `overflow-y`: scroll;

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XKHyq/)