# How do I make the scrollbar on a div only visible when necessary?

Tags: css, html, scrollbar

I have this div:

```
<div style='overflow:scroll; width:400px;height:400px;'>here is some text</div>
```

The scrollbars are always visible, even though the text does not overflow. I want to make the scrollbars only be visible when necessary - that is, only visible when there is enough text in the box that they are needed. Like a textarea does. How do I do this? Or is my only option to style a textarea so it looks like a div?

Comment: What about this. Shows only the scrollbar when hovered over. Not sure if this is useful to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125185/hide-scrollbar-and-show-on-hover-like-facebooks-new-chat-sidebar

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QwLeMG
Hope this can help you

Comment: `overflow: auto;` doesn't work on Android :-(

Answer (score 523, accepted):

Use `overflow: auto`. Scrollbars will only appear when needed.

(Sidenote, you can also specify for only the x, or y scrollbar: `overflow-x: auto` and `overflow-y: auto`).

Comment: Note that overflow-y does only work if you specify `max-height`

Comment: overflow-y doesn't need max-height. I never used max-height with overflow-y and it worked everytime.

Comment: @Sumafu you may need it depending on the case, as I could experience right now.

Comment: You would need `height` or `max-height` set if you're using `absolute` or `fixed` position on the overflow element as these prevent the element from resizing based on page or viewport boundaries.

Answer (score 17):

try this:

```
<div style='overflow:auto; width:400px;height:400px;'>here is some text</div>
```

Answer (score 12):

Change **overflow** property of CSS `block` to **`auto`**.

```
overflow: auto;
```

It will automatically add a scrollbar to the left only when needed.

Answer (score 9):

try

```
<div style='overflow:auto; width:400px;height:400px;'>here is some text</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

try

```
<div id="boxscroll2" style="overflow: auto; position: relative;" tabindex="5001">
```

Answer (score 2):

I found that there is height of div still showing, when it have text or not. So you can use this for best results.

```
<div style=" overflow:auto;max-height:300px; max-width:300px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`overflow : auto` is the magical code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.ex1 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

div.ex2 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.ex3 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  overflow: auto;
}

div.ex4 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  overflow: clip;
}

div.ex5 {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  overflow: visible;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The overflow Property</h1>

<p>The overflow property specifies whether to clip content or to add scrollbars when an element's content is too big to fit in a specified area.</p>

<h2>overflow: scroll:</h2>
<div class="ex1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</div>

<h2>overflow: hidden:</h2>
<div class="ex2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</div>

<h2>overflow: auto:</h2>
<div class="ex3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</div>

<h2>overflow: clip:</h2>
<div class="ex4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</div>

<h2>overflow: visible (default):</h2>
<div class="ex5">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below one:

```
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow-x: visible; overflow-y: scroll;">Text</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. This solution works best if you don't have specific height/width (a more dynamic UI.)

Answer (score 0):

[Stackblitz Playgrond](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-xkvpvz?file=me.html)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
    #scrollable-content {
        background: #eee;
        height: 150px;
        width: 400px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="original-content"> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </div>
    <br />
    <div id="scrollable-content"> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </div>
</body>

</html>
```