# Scrollbar behaviour changes when connected to an external monitor

Tags: css, macos, scrollbar, overflow, hdmi

I have a vertical menu which is scrollable on the Y axis with `overflow-y: scroll`. I'm on a MBP16 and on both Chrome and Safari the scrollbar for this div only appears when I hover it, [looking like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCskk.png)

But when I connect my MBP16 to a 1080p display the scrollbar remains visible and [with a different look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y49kv.png).

I know it might be an OS setting but is there any workaround to this? Specially to get the scrollbar showing only when hovered. I've already tried `overflow-y: hidden` to the regular div and `overflow-y: scroll` to its :hover, but it remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

Since [setting the overflow to none and changing it to overflow scroll on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7125688/4279493) didn't work for you,

I suggest using the Jquery plugin [nanoScrollerJS](http://jamesflorentino.github.io/nanoScrollerJS/)

It gives an easy way of adding Mac OS X Lion-styled scrollbars for your website which **only appear when hovered** as you requested.